# ubuntu ssd install issue

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, installation, ssd

Was not able to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS or 11.10 on SSD OCZ Vertex 3 120GB

Installer crashed.
There is no more information. Installer promised to report issue to Ubuntu.

Do I have to prepare something to install Ubuntu?
Hardware is quite fresh:

- **CPU**: i5 2500
- **Motherboard**: ASUS P8H67-M LX/SI
- **Video Card**: Asus NVIDIA EN210 SILENT/DI/1GD3/V2

Comment: I would check the installation media (CD?) first....

Comment: I tried 12.04 and 11.10. media is ok. We have 12.04 from same source installed on same machine.

Comment: The problem was in firmware.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B004Q81CKY this was the SSD I was talking about.

I hope this will be helpful who will use ssd with Ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04 LTE

http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?99275-NEW!-Bootable-Linux-based-tools-for-OCZ-SSD-s&p=714069&viewfull=1#post714069

We had to set AHCI in BIOS to be able to update firmware. The rest was same as usually.